# How to convert the Cartesian coordinate to image coordinate in FreeType

Tags: image, opencv, fonts, coordinate, freetype

Recently, I worded on OCR in Chinese characters, I wanna use **FreeType(2.3.5)** to collect the samples of character, here's my code :

```
FT_Library fontLibrary;
FT_Face fontFace;
int fontSize = 64;

// Initialize
FT_Init_FreeType(&fontLibrary);
FT_New_Face(fontLibrary, "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simhei.ttf", 0, &fontFace);

// Setup
FT_Select_Charmap(fontFace, FT_ENCODING_UNICODE);
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(fontFace, fontSize, 0);
FT_Load_Char(fontFace, 'H', FT_LOAD_RENDER);

// Retrieve data
FT_GlyphSlot & glyphSlot = fontFace->glyph;
FT_Bitmap charBitmap = glyphSlot->bitmap;
int charWidth = charBitmap.width;
int charHeight = charBitmap.rows;
unsigned char* charBuffer = charBitmap.buffer;

// Construct image
Mat fontImage(fontSize, fontSize, CV_8UC1);
fontImage = Scalar::all(0);
for (int y = 0; y < charHeight; y++)
{
    int row = fontSize - glyphSlot->bitmap_top + y;
    for (int x = 0; x < charWidth; x++)
    {
        int col = glyphSlot->bitmap_left + x;
        fontImage.at<uchar>(row, col) = charBuffer[y*charWidth + x];
    }
}

imshow("Font Image", fontImage);
waitKey(0);

// Uninitialize
FT_Done_Face(fontFace);
FT_Done_FreeType(fontLibrary);
```

The problem is : the character is **not center aligned in image**, the coordinate of character image looks strange, in this example, the coordinate of **'H'** character is (fontSize = 64) :

```
bitmap_left = 3
bitmap_top = 44
bitmap.width = 26
bitmap.rows = 43
```

then convert to the coordinate of image :

```
ROI.left = bitmap_left = 3;
ROI.right = bitmap_left + bitmap.width = 29;
ROI.top = fontSize - bitmap_top = 20;
ROI.bottom = fontSize - bitmap_top + bitmap.rows = 63;
```

so the margin in 4-direction is :

```
ROI.leftMargin = 3;
ROI.rightMargin = 64 - 29 = 35;
ROI.topMargin = 20;
ROI.bottomMargin = 64 - 63 = 1;
```

IT IS NOT CENTER ALIGNED !!!

Answer (score -1):

I solve the problem by myself, the left-top coordinate of image is stored in **glyphSlot**, here's the blog :
**http://kang.blog.com/2013/09/21/how-to-convert-the-cartier-coordinate-to-image-coordinate-in-freetype/**

Comment: This answer's link is now dead.  Perhaps an edit is needed as I came here looking for Freetype info.